# Enable CORS on Cloudant local

Tags: javascript, docker, cors, cloudant

I have setup a cloudant local database using docker image.

When I try to send in a cloudant query using a JavaScript application hosted on localhost:8000 it gives me an CORS error.

How do I enable CORS on Cloudant local? I have tried the following

1. PUT request as described in https://docs.cloudant.com/cors.html#setting-the-cors-configuration
2. Checked the dashboard but the local instance does not have the "Account" tab available.
   [image: Cloudant Local dashboard]

Comment: What's the content of the CORS config file?

Comment: When I GET the CORS config file using http://localhost:9991/cloudant-db/_api/v2/admin/config/cors, I get the following JSON. {
  "error": "not_found",
  "reason": "missing"
}

Comment: Shouldn't that be `localhost:9991/_api/v2/user/config/cors`?

Comment: I also tried that, it gives { "error": "not_found",  "reason": "Database does not exist."}.

Comment: You probably need SSL. I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as @anirus, but there's a *very* kludgy way around it. If you have named the container `cloudant-developer` as in the current instructions at https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/cloudant-developer/:

- Save the stock `default.ini` file locally:

  `docker exec cloudant-developer cat /opt/cloudant/etc/default.ini > default.ini`
- Modify it so that `enable_cors = true` instead of `false`
- In the `[cors]` section, add a line like `origins = http://localhost:3000`. It should also take a comma delimited list, but then you're probably only working on one app at a time.
- Volume mount the modified `default.ini` over the original whenever you run the container by adding `` -v `pwd`/default.ini:/opt/cloudant/etc/default.ini `` to **docker**'s list of command line arguments:

  `` docker run --privileged --detach --volume cloudant:/srv -v `pwd`/default.ini:/opt/cloudant/etc/default.ini --name cloudant-developer --publish 8080:80 --hostname cloudant.dev ibmcom/cloudant-developer ``

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a custom Dockerfile which edits the Cloudant settings file before the database is started. I used this -

```
FROM ibmcom/cloudant-developer:latest

RUN \
  sed -i 's/enable_cors = false/enable_cors = true/g' /opt/cloudant/etc/default.ini && \
  sed -i 's/\[cors\]/\[cors\]\norigins=*/g' /opt/cloudant/etc/default.ini && \
  sed -i 's/credentials = false/credentials = true/g' /opt/cloudant/etc/default.ini
```

It will enable cors with `origins=*` and also accept credentials from CORS connections.

You can put that in a `Dockerfile`, then `docker build` and `docker run` it.

Answer (score 0):

All my investigation so far indicates that this is not supported on local Cloudant.